# How to store bulk questions in android sqlite db?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on quiz application. In my project I need to store **huge number of questions** to display on the screen. How can I do that? I have downloaded the sqlite browser and when I tried to import .sql file it is displaying error. Also I have kept the .sql file in **assets folder in eclipse**.

**How to store those questions into my sqlite db?**

Comment: You really need to add more information for anyone to be able to answer this. What error do you get? How does the .sql look like? Does it have the necessary schema changes in it, or did you have to create the schema beforehand? Etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that even if you port the .sql file to the assets folder in eclipse its not going to work like that when you are going to use it in a real android mobile rather that an emulator by using the final .apk file.

One method what i did was to enter all the entries using a method. In order not to do this at each load, i check if the number of entries is the same else i drop the table and then enter it new once again. Thats the option that i know of. Maybe there are better options. But this works for sure.

```
public long createValue(int semester, String subname, int credits)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_SEMESTER, semester);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SUBNAME, subname);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CREDITS, credits);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); 
}
```

Create a method like the above to enter the values and then call this method with the values to enter. So you can just have n number of calls to this method with the values to enter.

```
mDb is a SQliteDatabase object
```

Maybe this will help you out.

Comment: BTW you have to create SQLiteDatabase. Check out this resource [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). I used it when i was searching for SQLite database usage.

Comment: Hi I have created a DATABASE in my sqlite browser and created table in it. I need to keep that abcd.sqlite file in assets folder. But how to get that file...I have saved that db name but when i saw the properties it is showing the file type as File. I need a .sqlite file of that table which I saved. Please let me know how to get .sqlite file from sqlite browser.